# how I configurate carrierwave with mongoid (3.0.17)?

Tags: mongoid, carrierwave

Here are my gem list,

- mongo (1.8.2)
- mongoid (3.0.17)
- mongoid-grid_fs (1.7.0)
- carrierwave (0.8.0)
- carrierwave-mongoid (0.4.0)

I have tried to generate an upload image but it dont work, the carrierwave.rb its looks like this:

```
require 'carrierwave/mongoid'
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.grid_fs_database = Mongoid::Config.sessions[:default]
    config.grid_fs_port = 27017
    config.grid_fs_host = '127.0.0.1'
    config.storage = :grid_fs
end
```

but puts an error:

```
/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `grid_fs_database=' for CarrierWave::Uploader::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
.....
```

there is a solution for that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick look at [the source for carrierwave-mongoid](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave-mongoid/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/mongoid.rb) and it appears that the configuration options you specified (`grid_fs_database`, `grid_fs_port`, and `grid_fs_host`) are not valid options - hence your error.

My understanding is that carrierwave-mongoid derives its mongoDB configuration from the Mongoid configuration, so there's no need to specify this again. You configuration should look something like this:

```
require 'carrierwave/mongoid'
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :grid_fs
    config.grid_fs_access_url = "/uploads" # or whatever you'd like the HTTP path to be
end
```

Comment: thx, i modified the carrierwave.rb file like you told that, it's work.             Arrierwave-mongoid derives its mongoDB configuration through a mongoid.yml, but i want to connect another grid_fs database, How do I configuration?

Comment: I don't believe there's support for that in carrierwave-mongoid as it stands. You might consider opening an issue on github and making a feature request or discussing that idea with the project's maintainer.